# Python date.today shows the next day

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm astounded by some code I wrote some time ago. For not entering in much detail i have a method that runs through some objects, wich have a date parameter. If the date parameter is equal to today's date, goes on.

I have set this in my local machine for test and have like 695 objects all with the same date, today, but when the action is run nothing happens, so i debug it to find that my expression `date.today()` returns `datetime.date(2014, 3, 19)`.

This is is incorrect, as the date of my computer from the `date` command is `Tue Mar 18 20:56:09 AST 2014`.

I used `from datetime import date`. This is one of the more cryptic errors i have ever got. Any experience someone can share here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `date.today` returns the date in GMT / UTC, not your local time zone.

Comment: Google tells me it is 1:45 AM March 19, 2014 GMT in Greenwich, London, UK.  datetime.date.today() gives datetime.date(2014, 3, 18) in Colorado.

Comment: And is possible that two different python shells running in the same computer would yield different results? Could the framework influence in the output of date.today()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not timezone aware and there's no platform-independent way to make it so. What is generally done is [incorporate something like pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and call .today() as:

```
datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo = pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: But then how come if i use the date command in my os, and what's more, in a python shell i call date.today() returns correctly?

Comment: Another comment, i tried that sentence in the debugger and still returned '2014-03-19'. I think the problem may be deeper.